# Making a test-connection script multi threaded

Tags: multithreading, powershell, ping, do-loops

This script takes input from a test file, writes the results to screen, file, and generates an email under certain conditions.  The issue is that it is extremely slow with a large lists of hosts.  I have looking into multi threading but I am a PS newbie and have not been able to figure it out.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the script.

```
# start looping here 
Do{ 
    $available = @() 
    $notavailable = @() 
    $ComputerName = @()

    #Path to text file of hostnames we want to monitor
    $ComputerName = Get-Content hosts.txt

    Write-Host (Get-Date) 

    # Read the File with the Hosts every cycle, this way to can add/remove hosts 
    # from the list without touching the script/scheduled task,  
    # also hash/comment (#) out any hosts that are going for maintenance or are down. 
    $ComputerName | Where-Object {!($_ -match "#")} |  
    #"test1","test2" | Where-Object {!($_ -match "#")} | 
    ForEach-Object { 
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 1 -ea silentlycontinue) 
        { 
            # if the Host is available then write it to the screen 
            $value = @()
            $value = $_
            Write-Host "Available host ---> "$_ -ForegroundColor Green 
            [String[]]$available += $_ 

            if ($value -notmatch "[a-z]")
            {   
                $hosttoip = @()
                $iptohost = @()
                $parsemac = @()
                $getmac = @() 
                $getmac = @()   
                $findstr = @()
                $iptoip = @()    
                $getmac = nbtstat -A $_ | findstr "Mac Address = **-**-**-**-**" | Select-String -Pattern "Mac Address" -SimpleMatch
                $iptoip = $_
                $iptohost = [System.Net.Dns]::gethostbyaddress($_).Hostname

                $findstr = findstr "$_" output.csv
                Write-Host $_ "Responds with:" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "Hostname" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "$iptohost" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host "IP Address:" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host "Mac Address:" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "$getmac`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            }
            if ($value -match "[a-z]")
            {
                $iptohost = @()
                $hosttoip = @()
                $hosttohost =@()
                $parsemac = @()
                $getmac = @() 
                $getmac = @()
                $findstr = @()
                $hosttohost = $_
                $getmac = nbtstat -a $_ | findstr "Mac Address = **-**-**-**-**" | Select-String -Pattern "Mac Address" -SimpleMatch

                $hosttoip = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($_).AddressList[0].IpAddressToString
                $findstr = findstr "$_" output.csv
                Write-Host $_ "Responds with:" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "Hostname" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "$_" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host "IP Address:" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "$hosttoip" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                Write-Host "Mac Address:" -ForegroundColor White
                Write-Host "$getmac`n" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            }
            if ($findstr -eq $Null)
            {
                $WriteFile = @()
                $WriteFile = "$_,$iptohost $hosttohost,$hosttoip $iptoip,$getmac"
                $WriteFile | Out-file output.csv -Encoding ascii -Append 
            }
            # if the Host was out and is now backonline, remove it from the OutageHosts list 
            if ($OutageHosts -ne $Null) 
            { 
                if ($OutageHosts.ContainsKey($_)) 
                { 
                    Write-host $_ "was on the outages list and came back online.  Sending email notification" -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    $OutageHosts.Remove($_) 
                    $Now = Get-date 
                    if ($notifyonServerBackOnline) 
                    { 
                        $Body = "$_ is online right now $getmac - If available, the MAC address and hostname/IP will be recorded in ScriptLocation\output.csv" 
                        Send-MailMessage -Body "$body" -to $tonotification -from $fromnotification -Subject "Monitored host $_ is up" -SmtpServer $smtpserver 
                    } 
                } 
            }   
        }
        else 
        { 
            # If the host is unavailable, give a warning to screen 
            Write-Host "Unavailable host ------------> "$_ -ForegroundColor Red 
            if(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $_ -Count 2 -ea silentlycontinue)) 
            { 
                # If the host is still unavailable for 4 full pings, write error and send email 
                Write-Host "Unavailable host ------------> "$_ -ForegroundColor Red
                [Array]$notavailable += $_ 

                if ($OutageHosts -ne $Null) 
                { 
                    if (!$OutageHosts.ContainsKey($_)) 
                    { 
                        # First time down add to the list and send email 
                        Write-Host "$_ Is not in the OutageHosts list, first time down" 
                        $OutageHosts.Add($_,(get-date)) 
                        $Now = Get-date 
                        if ($notifyonServerDown) 
                        { 
                            $Body = "$_ has not responded for 5 pings at $Now" 
                            Send-MailMessage -Body "This message was generated by our ping monitoring script`n$body" -to $tonotification -from $fromnotification -Subject "Host $_ is down" -SmtpServer $smtpserver 
                        } 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        # If the host is in the list do nothing for 1 hour and then remove from the list. 
                        Write-Host "$_ Is in the OutageHosts list" 
                        if (((Get-Date) - $OutageHosts.Item($_)).TotalMinutes -gt $EmailTimeOut) 
                        {
                            $OutageHosts.Remove($_)
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    # First time down create the list and send email 
                    Write-Host "Adding $_ to OutageHosts." 
                    $OutageHosts = @{$_=(get-date)} 
                    $Now = Get-date 
                    if ($notifyonServerDown) 
                    { 
                        $Body = "$_ has not responded for 5 pings at $Now" 
                        Send-MailMessage -Body "This message was generated by our ping monitoring script`n$body" -to $tonotification -from $fromnotification -Subject "Host $_ is down" -SmtpServer $smtpserver 
                    } 
                }
            }
        } 
    }

    Write-Host "" 
    Write-Host "Sleeping $SleepTimeOut seconds" 
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $SleepTimeOut 
    if ($OutageHosts.Count -gt $MaxOutageCount) 
    { 
        # If there are more than a certain number of host down in an hour abort the script. 
        $Exit = $True 
        $body = $OutageHosts | Out-String 

        if ($notifyonMaxOutageCount) 
        { 
            Send-MailMessage -Body "This message was generated by our ping monitoring script`n$body" -to $tonotification -from $fromnotification -Subject "More than $MaxOutageCount Hosts down, monitoring aborted" -SmtpServer $smtpServer 
        } 
    } 
}
while ($Exit -ne $True)
```

Comment: I'd suggest looking into the `*-Job` cmdlets or if you're feeling fancy, `runspace`s.  [Your question is too broad, however.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)